# Pick List showing error Property 'name' not found on type java.lang.String

Tags: java, jsf, exception, primefaces

I am using primefaces pick list and getting the error as the question stated. Posting only problem relative code. 
**XHTML Page**

```
<p:row>
  <p:column>
  <p:outputLabel style="font-size:12px;" styleClass="labelCaption" 
  for="bank" value="Bank(s) Name :" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column colspan="3">
  <p:pickList id="bank" style="font-size:12px;" required="true" value="#{eipoIRBean.dualbanks}" var="dbanks" itemLabel="#{dbanks.name}" itemValue="#dbanks}"> 
  <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Available Banks</f:facet>
  <f:facet name="targetCaption">Selected Banks</f:facet>
  </p:pickList>
  </p:column>
  </p:row>
  <p:row>
  <p:column colspan="4" align="left"
  styleClass="panelGridFooter ui-widget-header">
  <p:commandButton id="submit" ajax="false"
  style="font-size:12px;" value="Save"
  action="#{eipoIRBean.submit}"
  icon="ui-icon-check">
  </p:commandButton>
  <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w"
  style="font-size:12px;" value="Cancel"
  action="listMyGroupLifeClaim?faces-redirect=true"
  immediate="true" global="true">
  </p:commandButton>
  </p:column>
  </p:row>
```

**Bean** is

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "eipoIRBean")
public class InvestorRegistrationBean implements Serializable{
    private InvestorSetupBusinessObj businessObj = new InvestorSetupBusinessObj();
    private DualListModel<Bank> dualbanks;

    public DualListModel<Bank> getDualbanks() {
        return dualbanks;
    }

    public void setDualbanks(DualListModel<Bank> dualbanks) {
        this.dualbanks = dualbanks;
    }

    public InvestorSetupBusinessObj getBusinessObj() {
        return businessObj;
    }

    public void setBusinessObj(InvestorSetupBusinessObj businessObj) {
    this.businessObj = businessObj;
    }

    public InvestorRegistrationBean(){ 
        dualList_of_banks();
    }
    public void dualList_of_banks(){
        dualbanks = new DualListModel<Bank>(businessObj.getInvestor().getBanks(), new ArrayList<Bank>());
    }
    public void submit() {
        businessObj.getInvestor().setBanks(dualbanks.getTarget());
        businessObj.save(); 
    } 
}
```

**Business object** is

```
public class InvestorSetupBusinessObj extends BaseBusinessObject {
    private Investor investor= new Investor();
    private InvestorRequestInvoker invoker = new InvestorRequestInvoker(this);
    private List<Map<String,Object>> dataGrid;

    public Investor getInvestor() {
        return investor;
    }

    public void setInvestor(Investor investor) {
    this.investor = investor;
    }

    public InvestorRequestInvoker getInvoker() {
        return invoker;
    }

    public void setInvoker(InvestorRequestInvoker invoker) {
            this.invoker = invoker;
    }

    public InvestorSetupBusinessObj(){
        getInvestor().setBanks(invoker.selectAllBank());
    }
}
```

**Bank.java class**

```
public class Bank implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private long id;
private String name;
private List<BankBranch> bankBranches;
private List<Investor> investors;
private List<InvestorJointHolder> investorJointHolders;
private List<PoBank> poBanks;
private List<PoSubscription> poSubscriptions;

public Bank() {
}


@Id
public long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


//bi-directional many-to-one association to BankBranch
@OneToMany(mappedBy="bank")
public List<BankBranch> getBankBranches() {
    return this.bankBranches;
}

public void setBankBranches(List<BankBranch> bankBranches) {
    this.bankBranches = bankBranches;
}


public BankBranch addBankBranches(BankBranch bankBranches) {
    getBankBranches().add(bankBranches);
    bankBranches.setBank(this);

    return bankBranches;
}

public BankBranch removeBankBranches(BankBranch bankBranches) {
    getBankBranches().remove(bankBranches);
    bankBranches.setBank(null);

    return bankBranches;
}

//bi-directional many-to-many association to Investor
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="banks")
public List<Investor> getInvestors() {
    return this.investors;
}

public void setInvestors(List<Investor> investors) {
    this.investors = investors;
}



//bi-directional many-to-one association to InvestorJointHolder
@OneToMany(mappedBy="bank")
public List<InvestorJointHolder> getInvestorJointHolders() {
    return this.investorJointHolders;
}

public void setInvestorJointHolders(List<InvestorJointHolder> investorJointHolders) {
    this.investorJointHolders = investorJointHolders;
}


public InvestorJointHolder addInvestorJointHolders(InvestorJointHolder investorJointHolders) {
    getInvestorJointHolders().add(investorJointHolders);
    investorJointHolders.setBank(this);

    return investorJointHolders;
}

public InvestorJointHolder removeInvestorJointHolders(InvestorJointHolder investorJointHolders) {
    getInvestorJointHolders().remove(investorJointHolders);
    investorJointHolders.setBank(null);

    return investorJointHolders;
}

//bi-directional many-to-one association to PoBank
@OneToMany(mappedBy="bank")
public List<PoBank> getPoBanks() {
    return this.poBanks;
}

public void setPoBanks(List<PoBank> poBanks) {
    this.poBanks = poBanks;
}


public PoBank addPoBanks(PoBank poBanks) {
    getPoBanks().add(poBanks);
    poBanks.setBank(this);

    return poBanks;
}

public PoBank removePoBanks(PoBank poBanks) {
    getPoBanks().remove(poBanks);
    poBanks.setBank(null);

    return poBanks;
}

//bi-directional many-to-many association to PoSubscription
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="banks")
public List<PoSubscription> getPoSubscriptions() {
    return this.poSubscriptions;
}

public void setPoSubscriptions(List<PoSubscription> poSubscriptions) {
    this.poSubscriptions = poSubscriptions;
}
```

}

My pick list is populating correctly with the above method `public InvestorSetupBusinessObj()` but when I select one bank and save it, it gives the following exception. Any help much appreciated.

**Stack Trace** is

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /eipo/investorRegistration.xhtml @367,59 itemLabel="#{dbanks.name}": Property 'name' not found on type java.lang.String
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at org.primefaces.component.picklist.PickList.getItemLabel(PickList.java:130)
at org.primefaces.component.picklist.PickListRenderer.encodeOptions(PickListRenderer.java:226)
at org.primefaces.component.picklist.PickListRenderer.encodeList(PickListRenderer.java:192)
at org.primefaces.component.picklist.PickListRenderer.encodeMarkup(PickListRenderer.java:86)
at org.primefaces.component.picklist.PickListRenderer.encodeEnd(PickListRenderer.java:59)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1826)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822)
at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeRow(PanelGridRenderer.java:148)
at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeStaticBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:110)
at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:63)
at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:49)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:74)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:204)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:121)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1826)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:847)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1819)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:447)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: value="#{eipoIRBean.dualbanks}" and value="#{eipoIRBean.dualbanks}" . You missed the { after the #.

Comment: @Adarsh i missed it while pasting the code, corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define a converter to make it work, it is necessary as guided in the primefaces manual when using picklist :

```
<p:pickList ... var="dbanks" itemValue="#{dbanks}" converter="BankConverter" >
```

Take a look here : [Custom converter in JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/)

Comment: Why would i need to do that? the problem is occurring when i am setting dual list target, dual list source is working fine.

Comment: @anas - A converter is mandatory when using a POJO in the picklist. Refer to the primefaces manual

Comment: oh wait , the converter is necessary, i will accept the answer after correcting and running. thanks @kolossus and omar